# I want to add a clique to my graph as a subgraph

Tags: python-3.x, list, combinations, traversal

I have my `Graph` class:

```
class Graph:
    V = set([])
    E = {}

    def add_vertex(self, u):
        self.V.add(u)
        self.E[u] = []

    def add_edge(self, u, v):
        if u not in self.V:
            self.add_vertex(u)
        if v not in self.V:
            self.add_vertex(v)
        self.E[u].append(v)
        self.E[v].append(u)

    def add_clique(self, *Q):
        for u, v in Q:
            self.add_edge(u, v)
```

the function `add_clique` must take arbitrary number of elements either separately, or as a list, and add them to the graph as a clique (complete subgraph).

So, the code given below should work:

```
G = Graph()
G.add_clique(1,2,3,4)
list = [5,6,7,8,9]
G.add_clique(*list)
G.add_clique(*[13,14,19,21])
```

However, I cannot traverse a list or a collection of arguments in pairs. When I execute this code:

```
G = Graph()
G.add_clique(5, 6, 7, 8)
```

I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/PycharmProjects/disks/main.py", line 63, in <module>
    G.add_clique(5, 6, 7, 8)
  File "D:/PycharmProjects/disks/main.py", line 21, in add_clique
    for u, v in Q:
TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable int object
```

What is the right way to do this?

Comment: Can you show exactly what you're tying to do and how exactly it fails?

Comment: @glibdud I addded the code and the error. Thanks for your notice.

Answer (score 1):

Basically your for-loop in `add_clique` is trying to read 2 items out of each item of Q. `for u, v in Q` *unpacks* each item into two variables, this only works if every element is exactly a 2-tuple. You can reproduce this by running the following in a python shell

```
>>> for u, v in (1, 2, 3, 4):
...   pass
```

For your subgraph use case, check out [itertools.combinations](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) to get all 2-tuples of the nodes list. The code could be as simple as

```
for u, v in itertools.combinations(Q, 2):
    self.add_edge(u, v)
```